# How to deploy Spring-boot REST API in external tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring-boot gradle application which is not having any web pages.This application is having REST api's which are successfully getting called when i am running it as a Spring boot application.

Now after generation war from gradle, when i am trying to deploy it in apache-tomcat-8.0.35, it's getting deployed and directory structure is as follows:-

[image: Directory Structure]

but now i am not able to access my REST api with tomcat port 8080. I have already checked tomcat is up at http://localhost:8080. On calling the REST Api I am getting the below error:

```
HTTP Status 403
```

Can anybody please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be access forbidden error. Please check your tomcat configuration if it has any filters installed or other configurations which is preventing the access.

Comment: Enabled Security ?

Comment: @PRATHAPS I have just downloaded a fresh copy of tomcat and deployed my application in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies in build.gradle:

```
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

And add a class:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```